# ms access -- Create new page tab with a subform and populate subform with data

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I would like to be able to do is when my EditInfo form is loaded, I want to is load the entire client info onto pages.

I want to be able to create a new tab on my TabCtrlEdit tabcontrol on the edit form, add a subform to the new tab and auto populate the subform with data stored in tables.

But I'm a little unsure how to go about this.

Thank you!

EDIT---
A little more info.
Each time the client comes they get a new record stored in my visits table.
What I would like to do is when the user goes to edit a clients information - It will loop through and give each visit a new tab with the visit subform populated with that visits data.
There could be a varying number of these visits so I would like it to be done when the form loads.
Right now the EditInfo form just loads the initial visit information (name, ID etc...) but not the rest of the visits as it is stored in a different table.

Comment: Why must you generate the Tabpages? Can you not just simply hide/show them with the <code>.visible<code> property? And: what is the Editinfo form? What do you mean by "entire client info"? What data from which tables? Be a bit more verbose, please

Comment: Just added some more info

Comment: Why don't you use a Subform for this and set the view mode to singleform?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Sorry I'm a little confused.

Comment: I assume you have a Client table and a Visits table. Standard procedure in Access would be use the Client table as a recordsource for the mainform and insert a subform which has the Visits table as a recordsource. A subform can have different view options.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Thank you.
I don't know how to insert a subform programmatically on to a form and set a recordsource. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Not programmatically, do it manually. I suggest you look at a few tutorials on basic Access and Database design before attempting VBA. There seems to be a massive design problem with your application. Or I am getting something very wrong.

Comment: What I want to know is how to programmatically have multiple subforms on the same main form.
I've got my application set up like you outlined above.

Comment: Each client will have an unknown amount of visits. So I need to load a form with all that information based on the ID number given.
I was hoping to be able to load multiple copies of the same subform (the form that I used to input the data in the first place) based on the number of visits the client has.
Does that help explain more clearly? Sorry for the confusion! Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Again: I suggest you look at a few tutorials on basic Access. A subform can hold all records of a table and display them like an Excel Sheet or as a paginated Form. Pls check the various online tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: They should be iterating through the visits on one form not jumping from form to form. Creating controls at runtime is a recipe for many disasters down the road.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was a little confused on the Continuous forms option but have it figured out now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have implemented thanks to everyone help!

From my main form I load the edit form using this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEdit", acNormal, , "ID='" & txtID.Value & "'", acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

I've got the ID linked to all tables corresponding to my subforms. (Via relationships).
And I just set the all the forms on the edit form to "Continuous".

Thanks again to everyone for their help!